# Heatmap for true-false or zeros-and-ones array

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, heatmap

I have an array of 500 results, which are 1 if true and 0 if false, and now i want to plot a color bar to display more graphically this results, showing an horizontal bar of 500 cells where the color of each bar represents true in green or false in red.

Is this possible? I was trying with colorbar function but I am not able to do so.

Comment: A [colorbar](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html#examples) is a bar that shows all of the possible colors/values used in a plot. Are you sure this is what you want? It sounds like you just want to make an image out of your array.

Comment: Hi @beaker yes, you are right. I was trying with colorbar because I didn't know any other function to try this, and didn't know if it was possible.. Masoud's answer was what I was searching for. Thanks for your help too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `imagesc`:

```
myArray = rand(1,500)>.4; %make a random array of zeros and ones

colormap('hot'); %change this to get the desired colors
imagesc(myArray);
set(gca,'ytick',[]) %remove y-axis ticks as they're not representing actual values
```

This will give you (made by [Octave](https://octave-online.net/)):

[image]

**Update: *How to make it look like a color-bar?***

```
colormap('hot');
imagesc(myArray);
set(gca,'ytick',[])
pbaspect([5 1 1]) %set the ratio of x-axis to y-axis
```

Plot would look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @masoud ! That's exactly what i was searching for. I've changed the colormap to 'redgreencmap' in order to have it red and green.

Comment: @inavas you're welcome. I updated my answer in case you want to make the plot looks like a color bar.